# Drupal 7 not showing admin tabs

Tags: 7

I've made a fresh Drupal installation, but for some reason I can't get to many administrative functions through links.

For example, this is the translation interface inside that installation:

[image]

It should look like the image below:

[image]

I've tried changing permissions, but nothing happens. And I can't see the "Permission" tab when accessing the people module either. Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: It'll only look like the 2nd image if you the overlay module turned on and you're browsing the admin pages in the overlay. Is the theme untouched?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help as you can see in the image below. And yes, I didn't make any theme modification. http://sites.ufop.br/error.jpg

Comment: As @Clive said, the difference between those screenshots is that the latter is using the overlay. So, your _it should look like the image below_ would just get _install and enable the Overlay module_ as answer. It would be better if you change the screenshots with others that show exactly what you are seeing, and describe what you are expecting to see.

Comment: Also, are you logged in as user #1? Because, in the case you aren't, you could not have access to the permissions page.